# Email client with automatic translation of inbound/outbound messages

Tags: web-apps, email, automation, translation, desktop-client

Is there any email client app that can do that, whether web app or desktop app? These are basically the requirements:

- add a POP3/IMAP account
- detect a language in inbound emails and autotranslate them to chosen language
- autotranslate outbound emails based on either the language of the inbound email(s) of the recipient or with some quick one-click functionality, such as a button

From what I've seen Microsoft Outlook has such an option for inbound emails. But it's not free, at least I can't see a way to add POP3/IMAP accounts on the free web version.